# biblatex philosophy-modern: a bug?

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-philosophy

I have found that `philosophy-modern.bbx` fails to start a new line when a translator (or anyone other than the author) is used instead of the author.

The minimal example is given below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test2.bib}
@book{bodhi:numerical,
    options = {usetranslator=true},
    translator = {Bhikkhu Bodhi},
    sortname = {Bodhi},
    title = {The Numerical Discourses of the Buddha},
    subtitle = {A Translation of the Anguttara Nikaya},
    shorttitle = {Numerical},
    year = 2012,
    address = {Somerville, MA},
    publisher = {Wisdom Publications}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=philosophy-modern, language=american,publocformat=loccolonpub]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test2.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

​
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This bug has been fixed in `biblatex-philosophy`. And update should solve this.

Indeed, `philopshy-modern` is missing the redefinition for the `bbx:translator` macro. It has redefininitions for `author` and `bbx:editor`.

We need

```
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:translator}[1]{%
 \ifboolexpr{%
    test \ifusetranslator
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{translator}}
  }%
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}%
       {}%
       {\printnames{translator}%
        \postsep%ADD
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extrayear}%
  \iffieldundef{label}%
    {\usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{translator}%
     \printtext{\addcomma\space}}
    {}}%
```

Comment: I have sent a bug report to the package author. Still waiting for a response.

Comment: well, no need to hold up your own work: in the meantime you should be able to put this in your own preamble and it will solve the bug for you.

Comment: @PaulStanley Thanks. I will do as you suggest. I have found another bug, I think, and will ask a new question.